# Returns filtered array of structs without push

Tags: solidity

I have this contract with an array of structs:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Tickets {
  struct Ticket {
    uint id;
    int val;
  }

  Ticket[] tickets;

  function addTicket(uint id, int val) public returns(bool success) {
    Ticket memory newTicket;
    newTicket.id = id;
    newTicket.val = val;
    tickets.push(newTicket);

    return true;
  }

  function getTicket(uint id) public view returns(Ticket memory) {
    uint index;

    for(uint i = 0; i<tickets.length; i++){
      if (tickets[i].id == id) {
        index = i;
        break;
      }
    }

    Ticket memory t = tickets[index];

    return t;
  }

  function findTickets(int val) public view returns(Ticket[] memory) {
    Ticket[] memory result;

    for(uint i = 0; i<tickets.length; i++){
      if (tickets[i].val == val) {
        result.push(tickets[i]); // HERE IS THE ERROR
      }
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

I need to returns a filtered by `val` array but when I buil this code: `result.push(tickets[i].id);` it throw this error:

`TypeError: Member "push" is not available in struct Tickets.Ticket memory[] memory outside of storage.`

How I can implement the filter without using `push` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using dynamic sized array, consider using mappings with a running counter. I would implement this contract as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Tickets {

  struct Ticket {
    uint id;
    int val;
  }

  mapping(uint => Ticket) tickets;
  uint ticketCount;


  function addTicket(uint id, int val) public returns(bool success) {
    tickets[ticketCount] = Ticket({
        id: id,
        val: val
    });
    ticketCount += 1;

    success = true;
  }

  function getTicket(uint id) public view returns(Ticket memory) {
    for(uint i = 0; i<ticketCount; i++){
      if (tickets[i].id == id) {
        return tickets[i];
      }
    }
  }

  function findTickets(int val) public view returns(Ticket[] memory filteredTickets) {
    Ticket[] memory ticketsTemp = new Ticket[](ticketCount);
    uint count;
    for(uint i = 0; i<ticketCount; i++){
      if (tickets[i].val == val) {
        ticketsTemp[count] = tickets[i];
        count += 1;
      }
    }

    filteredTickets = new Ticket[](count);
    for(uint i = 0; i<count; i++){
      filteredTickets[i] = ticketsTemp[i];
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Taking @Newti 's answer into consideration.. if you need to filter your tickets by `val`, you could also just create a mapping just for that.

`mapping(int => Ticket[]) filterByVal; // Val -> Ticket[]`

Then, on the `addTicket()`, you would also have to push the new Ticket to the map.